# ng update - The installed Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to upgrade an old app to the latest version of Angular (7 -> 14).
I successfully upgraded Angular from 7 to 8 (going step by step), but I can't update Angular Material.

When I run the command `ng update @angular/material@8`, I get the following:

> The installed Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
>
> Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
>
> Installing packages for tooling via npm.
>
> Installed packages for tooling via npm.
>
> Node.js version v10.24.1 detected.
>
> The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.15, or v16.10.

I've also tried those:

`npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/material@8`

`npx @angular/cli@9 update @angular/material@8`

`.\node_modules\.bin\ng update @angular/material@8`

But I always get the same error.

I do not want to upgrade the version of node at the moment as it makes the `npm install` process a real pain with old packages.

How can I simply use my local version of cli ?

Local AND global versions of CLI are `8.3.29`